# Kafka Source in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-xd, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am migrating from Spring XD to Spring Cloud Data Flow. When I am looking for module list I realised that some of the sources are not listed in Spring Cloud Flow - One of them is KAFKA source.

My question is why KAFKA source is removed from standard sources list in spring cloud data flow ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When I am looking for module list I realised that some of the sources are not listed in Spring Cloud Flow

Majority of the applications are ported over and the remaining are incrementally prioritized - you can keep track of the remaining subset in the [backlog](https://waffle.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters).

> My question is why KAFKA source is removed from standard sources list in spring cloud data flow ?

Kafka is not removed and in fact, we are highly opinionated about Kafka in the context of streaming use-cases so much so that it is baked into the DSL directly. More details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-explicit-destination-names).

For instance,

(i) if you've to consume from a Kafka topic (*as a source*), your stream definition would be:

`stream create --definition ":someAwesomeTopic > log" --name subscribe_to_broker --deploy`

(ii) if you've to write to a Kafka topic (*as a sink*), your stream definition would be:

`stream create --definition "http --server.port=9001 > :someAwesomeTopic" --name publish_to_broker --deploy`

(*where *someAwesomeTopic* is the named destination, a topic name*)

Comment: any working example of how to do this?, I wrote a very simple console app that uses a kafka producer to send the string "testme" and connect a stream to sand that to a file, and it is failing trying to convert the message: o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder : Could not convert message: 746573746D65    . This number is the ascii representation of the message "testme"

Comment: I assume this DSL shortcut uses the same Kafka cluster that Data Flow Server itself uses as a broker for a stream. This is not exactly the same as consuming a message from some Kafka cluster. This is possible with RabbitMQ that has both source and sink streaming apps. But Kafka ones are surprisingly missing.