# what is the property to accept binary json message in spring-cloud-stream kafka binder

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring-cloud-stream kafka binder to consume messages from a kafka topic. The source system is sending the json message in ascii. When My consumer listens to the topic it throws

```
o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder    : Could not convert message: 7B22736..
```

Is there any property that I can set in my .yml file to deserialize it? or is there an example that I can look into?

Comment: @ka2 I saw your comment in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548384/kafka-source-in-spring-cloud-data-flow) did you ever found the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by `json in hexadecimal-binary data` if you mean it's ascii data in a `byte[]`, try adding `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=text/plain` (or `application/json`).

Comment: Edited my question, The error is thrown when I am using content-type:application/json.

Comment: Did you try text/plain? Or you can set the `spring.kafka.consumer.valueDerserializer` to `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer`.

Comment: When I used text/plain it's able to convert to the json however in the console it still throws the same error. I cannot find the spring.kafka.consumer.valueDerserializer property in the spring cloud stream kafka binder that I am using.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry; that was just added yesterday (Boot 1.5 support) [commit here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/6a31e9c94f604f7054dd4f50f905da4d8edd5c78). I am not sure how to override the key/value deserializers with earlier binders.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the configuration property here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_consumer_properties

In your case, you can set this by doing the following:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.configuration.value.deserializer=<Deserialzier class>
```

Kafka binder takes all properties from the configuration map. Thus you can use any generic Kafka consumer properties and pass them this way.

Answer (score 0):

When I added `content-type:plain/text` and `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<subscriptionChannel>.consumer.‌​headerMode:raw` it worked.

Thank you!